# How to define function conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to set a function to the result of a ternary operator (that is returning one of two functions) and then call the result.  My code looks like this:

```js
const bar = (x: number) => {
  // do something
}

const foo = (x: number) => {
  // do something else
}

const my_function = condition ? bar : foo;

my_function(x)
```

but I get a type error that my_function is not a function.  Why doesn't this work, and how can I make it work? I have to call this function many times which is why I want to do it like this and not just call conditionally.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4wLwwBQA8BcMwCuAtnAKZICUaAfDAN4CwAUDDAPRswAmIMEIRUlAAWASzABzZgF9mzUJFgAzEL3TY8hEuSqpajFu048+AoWMkxSAGwikZcpl1LBryUjAXRP4LqKii4HhwqtakCGAA3I5esEQAngD6SgRgwAHgaD5gfhlgMAD88MgweCog0UzMYbBYWQAMjgnJqemBYNgUQA)

Comment: When you hover your cursor over `my_function` what type does your editor say that variable is?

Comment: the type is ((x) => void)

Comment: the type of the original function bar is (x) => void - without the extra set of parenthesis maybe that's something?

Comment: Do you get this error at runtime or compiletime? You have tagged this question with React.js. Does that have any part in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@m-s7's answer works. However, it's kind of messy.

IMHO better to commit something like this to production instead:

```
const bar = (x: number) => {
  // do something
}

const foo = (x: number) => {
  // do something else
}

const my_function = (x: number) => condition ? bar(x) : foo(x)
```

Here, you are creating a function in which you pass in the arg and return the result from the correct function based on the condition.
It's pretty clean and easy to understand at a glance.

Comment: thanks this worked! Think it was just something weird with the type checking.